# will powerline networking between 2 side-by-side house work?

Tags: networking

i am supposed to do a home networking thing for this two houses side-by-side. so, will powerline work?

i don't know much about the type of electrical wiring here, but if it is of any help its is in malaysia.

thanks

EDIT: ok i guess no powerline then.. but erica a wireless bridge would half the available bandwidth right? then it wont be suitable because ideally they want to be able to send large files to a central nas.

Comment: Why not just use a wireless bridge?

Comment: A wireless bridge would have as much bandwidth as powerline if set up correctly and without major interference (power lines, brick walls, etc), though there are often work-arounds depending on what is interfering. You can also bury a cable in waterproofed PVC pipe between the houses if it is not very far, it would be fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

Depending upon where you live, you may find that your next door neighbour is on a different [phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power) to yourself, meaning, that there is no electrical connection between your houses.

If the houses are on different phases, you should be aware of the dangers of making an electrical connection between the two houses, as you increase the potential difference from 240v to 415v (in europe, not sure what 110v equates to in the US).

Comment: Line-line is a factor sqrt(3) greater than phase-neutral, so US 120 V has a line-line voltage of 208 V.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally no.  Various people have told me that (in the UK at least) the electic companies have filters to condition the line power (as it enters your house) which cause the RF used by powerline networking to be filterd out.  That may be urban myth however.  I would be inclined to try and borrow a piar and test it for real.

Comment: In Germany it is forbidden by some electricity providers.